# How to resovle wcf Odata error

Tags: linq, wcf, odata

When we are running linq query over the odata then we are getting following error message

> "Error processing response stream. Server failed with following
>   message:\r\nAn error occurred while processing this request."

And detail description  are as

```
System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryRead()
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryStartReadFeedOrEntry()
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryReadEntry(MaterializerEntry& entry)
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.<LazyReadEntries>d__0.MoveNext()
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.Read()
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ReadNextFeedOrEntry()
    System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataEntityMaterializer.ReadImplementation()
    at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.Read()
    at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
    at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__94`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
```

I did not understand above error. Please help me determine the solution of this error. My code is :

```
    var t1 = _odataOEntities.ViewGetTicketDetails.AddQueryOption("$filter", Filter).Execute().ToList();
```